# Remove terms from a text

Tags: r

I need to remove certain terms from a text:

```
 texts
 [1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
 [2] "consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

that fully match (i.e., whole term):

```
  stopwords=read.csv("stopwords.txt", encoding = "UTF-8") 

  stopwords

  [1] Lorem
  [2] elit
  [3] a
```

Results:

```
 texts
 [1] "ipsum dolor sit amet"
 [2] "consectetur adipiscing"
```

I have tried removeWords but it does not work.

Thanks!
majesus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `removeWords` from `tm` package?
It works in my case:

```
 texts <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "consectetur adipiscing elit")
 stopwords <- c("Lorem","elit", "a")
 require("tm")
 trimws(removeWords(texts,stopwords))
```

Output:

```
[1] " ipsum dolor sit amet"  
[2] "consectetur adipiscing "
```

From @rajnim's answer using `trimws` function

### Using `gsub`

```
trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b(",paste(stopwords, collapse="|"),")\\b"), "", texts))
```

Comment: The number of stopwords is very high (> 100.000 stopwords), and also the number of texts > 1.000.000. Which option is more efficient?

Comment: I believe `removeWords` from `tm` package should be more efficient; if not it is more concise and I would choose that over `gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is using `gsub`:

```
texts = c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet a","consectetur adipiscing elit")
stopwords = c("Lorem","elit","a")
trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b(",paste(stopwords, collapse="|"),")\\b"), "", texts))
```

`trimws` removes the leading and trailing whitespaces

Comment: Thanks for `trimws` function. May be you forgot an `a` in stopwords. This will delete all `a`s

Comment: @discipulus thanks for pointing that out and the updated regex. copying it here.